# ER modeling in IDEF1x notation

Tags: database, database-design

i'm looking for freeware CASE editor for modeling in IDEF1x notation, something like ERWin. Any variants for Windows or Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/